# Are there applications of OR in art?

Tags: applications

As the title says, I was wondering if there are applications of optimization in art.
I am mainly thinking about visual arts e.g., painting, drawing, sculpture, but any other form of art would be interesting, e.g., music.

Comment: https://punkrockor.com/2015/05/22/domino-optimization-art/

Comment: Solving the TSP with cities located in intentional coordinates creates interesting works of art. Examples can be found in https://www2.oberlin.edu/math/faculty/bosch/tspart-page.html and codes to generate this works of art can be found in https://github.com/matthras/tsp-art-python .

Answer (score 6):

[Opt Art](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0691164061) takes you into some of the applications esp. in visualizing patterns\tiles\covers. Also entire computer vision & ML into correctly identifying images is based on optimizing a loss function.
Sill I guess applying optimization techniques to art does require some serious investment of time & effort. Like what factors (variables) do the average human eye and senses find most appealing? What are the recipes (variables) that make a movie a hit?
Though running ML algorithms like random forests often give out a probability of profiles of movies or art that are most likely to capture human emotions or senses, I dont think there's a serious thinking into identifying the impact (reduced cost/price) of different variables that go into that.

Comment: +1 for Opt Art.  I have this book, and it is very enjoyable.  The author, Bob Bosch, is the same person whose domino artwork is featured in the post linked by @Kuifje.

Comment: Is there a better URL for that link? It asks me to verify that I'm a human, which I can't do because I'm not.